# Uso de break dentro de un if y bucle for no funciona en java

Tags: java

Intento verificar si existe una vocal en una cadena, si la encuentra uso break; para romper el ciclo y devolver un mensaje, pero no funciona.

```
        String palabra="manzana";
        String[] arrayPalabra=palabra.split("");
        String[] vocales=new String[]{"a","e","i","o","u"};
        var listVocals=Arrays.asList(vocales);
        for (int i=0;i<arrayPalabra.length;i++) {
            boolean existe = listVocals.contains(arrayPalabra[i]);
            if(existe==true){
                System.out.println("Existe vocal");
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("NO Existe vocal"); 
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vista que solo necesitas saber si tu palabra contiene vocal o no, necesitarías primero que se ejecute tu bucle y después evaluar las condicionales, ya que si haces uso del `break` en ambas condicionales `if | else` tu bucle se rompe

```
    var listVocals=Arrays.asList(vocales);
    boolean existe=false;
    for (String arrayDatos : arrayPalabra) {
        existe = listVocals.contains(arrayDatos);
     }
     if(existe){
            System.out.println("Existe vocal");  
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO Existe vocal"); 
            
        }
```

// usando break solo cuando se obtenga vocal en la palabra

```
for(String arrayDatos : arrayPalabra){
            existe = listVocals.contains(arrayDatos);
            if(existe){
               System.out.println("tiene vocal");
               break;
            }

        } if(!existe){System.out.println("no tiene vocal");}
```

Comment: En caso de que sean millones de palabras no hay manera de romper el ciclo cuando encuentre la primera coincidencia de una vocal y así evitar recorrer todo el bucle del array?

Comment: pero que pasa si una de esas palabras lleva la vocal en la ultima letra?? no puedes asumir que siempre  este al inicio o en el medio y usar break para romper el recorrido

Comment: en tal caso ,tendrias que usar el break solo cuando se obtenga una vocal y usar otra condicional if fuera del bucle en caso no se obtenga vocal en la palabra

Comment: Se podría evitar el problema de las palabras largas, primero eliminando las repeticiones y luego siguiendo el algoritmo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías inicializar a `listVocals` como una lista del tipo `String`. También (por lógica), tu condición `if` debería debería estar fuera del bucle `for`, ya que sino retornaría `true` o `false` para cada caracter de la cadena que te retorna el `.split()`, y lo que necesitamos es solo un `true` o `false`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String palabra = "mzn";
    String[] arrayPalabra = palabra.split("");
    String[] vocales = new String[]{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    
    List<String> listVocals = Arrays.asList(vocales);
    boolean existe = false;
    
    for (String arrayDatos : arrayPalabra) {
        existe = listVocals.contains(arrayDatos);
    }
    if (existe == true) {
        System.out.println("Existe vocal");
        } else {
        System.out.println("NO Existe vocal");
    }
}
```